# Issue to open IOS app using costum URL scheme IONIC

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am getting some issue in [this](http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url%20schemes-ionic-framework-app/#comment-7382) Cordova plugin. I do not know where I am doing wrong.

I am not able to call my app in IOS. Android is working fine.

I register my app with `mytest://`

So my issue is:-

```
$scope.appOpen = function(){ 
    $scope.finalData.TrustedToken=md5.createHash($scope.finalData.agentid+$sco  pe.finalData.Caller+$scope.finalData.key);
    var data =  JSON.stringify($scope.finalData);
    window.open('mytest://'+data, '_system');
}
```

that code is working fine in Android but in IOS not working.

If I append simple string that is opening my app and also getting that URL there in handler. But above code not able to open other app

```
window.open('mytest://testData', '_system');
```

but that code is working fine. so how can i put variable in URL.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? You say it isn't working, so window.open does nothing for you in iOS? But then you say if you append a simple string it does something - I can't quite tell.